# Proof that $f^{-1}(\bigcap\limits_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu}) = \bigcap\limits_{\mu\in M}f^{-1}(B_{\mu})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Consider $f\colon A\to B$ a function and $(B_\mu)_{\mu \in M}$ a family of subsets of $B$.

I have to prove that $f^{-1}(\bigcap\limits_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu}) = \bigcap\limits_{\mu\in M}f^{-1}(B_{\mu})$ and $f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu}) = \bigcup\limits_{\mu \in M}f^{-1}(B_{\mu})$.

Instead of proving $A\subseteq B$ and then proving $B\subseteq A$ (for any sets $A,B$), I've decided to use $\iff$ all along.

1. $f^{-1}(\bigcap\limits_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu}) = \bigcap\limits_{\mu\in M}f^{-1}(B_{\mu})$

\begin{align*}
        x\in f^{-1}(\bigcap\limits_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu}) &\iff f(x)\in B_\mu \ \text{for all} \ \mu \in M\\
        & \iff \exists x\in A \ \text{such that} \ f(x)\in B_\mu \ \text{for all} \ \mu \in M\\
        &\iff x\in f^{-1}(B_\mu) \ \text{for all} \ \mu \in M\\
        &\iff x\in \bigcap_{\mu\in M} f^{-1}(B_\mu)
\end{align*}

2. $f^{-1}(\bigcup\limits_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu}) = \bigcup\limits_{\mu \in M}f^{-1}(B_{\mu})$
   \begin{align*}
           x\in f^{-1}(\bigcup_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu}) &\iff f(x)\in B_\mu \ \text{for some} \ \mu \in M\\
           & \iff \exists x\in A \ \text{such that} \ f(x)\in B_\mu \ \text{for some} \ \mu \in M\\
           &\iff x\in f^{-1}(B_\mu) \ \text{for some} \ \mu \in M\\
           &\iff x\in \bigcup_{\mu\in M} f^{-1}(B_\mu)   
   \end{align*}

They seemed too alike to me, which felt strange. Any correction or proof-writing tip is obviously appreciated.

Comment: What is $X$ in this context?

Comment: I suppose that you mean by $X$ the domain of the function $f$.  In the second lines of both equivalences, you must to delet the sing $\exists$ because in the begining you fix $x$. So that second lines are superfluous.

Comment: @angieduque Oops! Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both proofs, the line that says "$\exists x \in X$ such that..." is wrong, since the $x$ is fixed once you started with the equivalence. Hence, the proof should be

> *Proof*. Let $x \in X$. Then
> \begin{align*}
> x \in f^{-1}\bigg(\bigcap_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu}\bigg) 
> & \iff f(x) \in \bigcap_{\mu \in M} B_{\mu} \\
> & \iff \textrm{for all $\mu \in M$, $f(x) \in B_\mu$} \\
> & \iff \textrm{for all $\mu \in M$, $x \in f^{-1}(B_\mu)$} \\
> & \iff x \in \bigcap_{\mu\in M} f^{-1}(B_\mu).
> \end{align*}

and for the union just replace the "all" words to "some".